# Monkey testing a SmartCard library

Tags: c#, multithreading, state

My definition of monkey testing is basically playing with a program in as if I was a monkey (press every button, unplug things, go in the wrong order..etc etc)

So I made a rather simple SmartCard library that when I "enable" it it just polls the smart card reader for a card, and reports back information. see code

```
private void CardStatusChange()
{
    readerState[0].dwCurrentState = SCardState.SCARD_STATE_UNAWARE;
    while (run)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        if (SCWrapper.SCardGetStatusChange(scHandle, UInt32.MaxValue, readerState, 1) == SCardFunctionReturnCodes.SCARD_S_SUCCESS)
        {
            readerState[0].dwCurrentState = readerState[0].dwEventState;
            SendCardStatus(readerState[0].dwEventState);
        }
    }
}

private void SendCardStatus(SCardState sCardState)
{
        //case SCardState.SCARD_STATE_UNAWARE:
        //case SCardState.SCARD_STATE_IGNORE:
        //case SCardState.SCARD_STATE_CHANGED:
        //case SCardState.SCARD_STATE_UNKNOWN:
        //case SCardState.SCARD_STATE_UNAVAILABLE:
        //case SCardState.SCARD_STATE_EMPTY:
    if (HasStateMask(sCardState, SCardState.SCARD_STATE_EMPTY))
        OnCardUnplugged(); //fire event
        //case SCardState.SCARD_STATE_PRESENT:
    if (HasStateMask(sCardState, SCardState.SCARD_STATE_PRESENT))
    {
        OnCardPluggedIn(); //fire event
        SendCardATR(readerState[0].rgbAtr); //fire event
    }
        //case SCardState.SCARD_STATE_ATRMATCH:
    OnATRMatch(HasStateMask(sCardState, SCardState.SCARD_STATE_ATRMATCH));
        //case SCardState.SCARD_STATE_EXCLUSIVE:
        //case SCardState.SCARD_STATE_INUSE:
    OnCardInUse(HasStateMask(sCardState, SCardState.SCARD_STATE_INUSE));
        //case SCardState.SCARD_STATE_MUTE:
        //case SCardState.SCARD_STATE_UNPOWERED:
}

private bool HasStateMask(SCardState theValue, SCardState theMask)
{
    return ((theValue & theMask) == theMask);
}
```

This part works as expected in that while my thread is running I can plug in and unplug a smartcard as often and as quickly as I want without problem. What I'm struggling with is the Threading portion of it. Visual Studio screams at me for using suspend and I found a bug when using suspend in my thread so I am taking that out (in other words don't comment on that) but this is how I "open" and "enable" my smart card

```
public override bool Open()
{
    readerThread = new Thread(CardStatusChange);
    //code here to setup the smart card
    return true;
}

public override bool Enable()
{
    run = true;
    //thread start checking for card events
    switch (readerThread.ThreadState)
    {//this is probably a mistake
        case ThreadState.AbortRequested:
            break;
        case ThreadState.Aborted:
            break;
        case ThreadState.Background:
            break;
        case ThreadState.Running:
            break;
        case ThreadState.StopRequested:
            break;
        case ThreadState.Stopped:
            break;
        case ThreadState.SuspendRequested:
            break;
        case ThreadState.Suspended:
            readerThread.Resume();//TODO remove

            break;
        case ThreadState.Unstarted:
            readerThread.Start();

            break;
        case ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
public override void Disable()
{
    run = false;
    readerThread.Suspend(); //TODO remove
}
```

I've never been too good at threading, but I do need this as a thread (I think I do atleast I am open to other ideas). So how should I really Enable and Disable? I used to just set run to true or false, but my monkey testing showed that this doesn't always work and sometimes Windows would cry that it can't start a running thread... SO I dunno what to do. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think I found the answer. It appears to be work. On the Disable instead of `readerThread.Suspend()` I change it to `readertThread.Join()`. Then I just check for the Unstarted flag for Enable and fire it up. So far it is working good with no hicups. still have further testing.

Comment: Can you post the answer you found as an answer? This will help future users.

Comment: @RyanGates Sure can... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested by Ryan Gates I should post my results. I don't remember the entire scope of what i did, but I do know where the code is :)

So the basics are that I want the thread to be able to exit without causing any strange hicups if the user decides to use my library incorrectly. So I made the thread turn into a background thread. I was able to remove the ugly switch statement and just check the appropriate bits are set to make sure I can start my thread (basically only allows one thread to read a smart card instead of multiple reading the same card)

On Disable what I did was set my flag to kill the loop in my readerThread thread. I then wait for it to exit by using the `thread.Join` Clear as mud??? I can try to clear up more if anyone has questions.

```
public override bool Open()
{
    //Code to setup SmartCard

    readerThread = new Thread(CardStatusChange);
    readerThread.IsBackground = true;

    return true;
}
public override bool Enable()
{
    run = true;
    //thread start checking for card events
    Globals.tracer.TraceInformation("Checking Thread State:{0}", readerThread.ThreadState);
    var startable = (readerThread.ThreadState & ThreadState.Unstarted);
    if (startable > 0)
        readerThread.Start();

    return true;
}
public override void Disable()
{
    run = false;
    if(readerThread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Unstarted)
        readerThread.Join();
}
```